# Wait for all query to finish and fill at the same time asynchronously

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, knex.js

I want to fill each object of the result of a query, with other querys, and I want to do all in asynchronously way

Here is an example of the way how I do actually

```
var q = knex.select().from('sector');
q.then(function (sectores) {
    var i = -1;
    (function getDetalles(sectores) {
        i++;
        if(i < sectores.length){
            knex.select().from('sector_detalle')
            .where('sector_id', sectores[i].id)
            .then(function (detalles) {
                // this what i want to do asynchronously
                sectores[i].sector_detalles = detalles;
                console.log(sectores[i]);
                getDetalles(sectores);
            });
        } else {
            res.send({sucess: true, rows: sectores});
        }
    })(sectores);
});
```

I do some reserch and found this [wait for all promises to finish in nodejs with bluebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511578/wait-for-all-promises-to-finish-in-nodejs-with-bluebird) 
is close to what I want but don't know how to implement

Comment: Am I missing something or does your code not contain a loop? Also, doesn't this semi-recursive way already work - what do you want to improve?

Comment: Is there any reason to run those queries sequentially instead of in parallel?

Comment: no any reason, can you tell me more about? and thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`map` method](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise) that works on a promise for an array, and will invoke an asynchronous (promise-returning) callback for each of the items in it:

```
knex.select().from('sector').map(function(sector) {
    return knex.select().from('sector_detalle')
    .where('sector_id', sector.id)
    .then(function(detalles) {
        sector.sector_detalles = detalles;
        // console.log(sector);
        return sector;
    });
}).then(function(sectores) {
    res.send({sucess: true, rows: sectores});
});
```

Comment: i'm gonna try and tell you how it was